# Why concatenating " " is better than leaving a space after the previous sentence?

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation

Why in some tutorials (for instance, the Codecademy's ones), the instructors (and their instructions) tend to concatenate a space `" "` instead of adding a space in the previous string?

Why they prefer doing this...

```
var nameString = function (name) {
    return "Hi, I am" + " " + name;
};

console.log(nameString("jim"));
```

Instead of this?

```
var nameString = function (name) {
    return "Hi, I am " + name;
};

console.log(nameString("jim"));
```

Notice the space after *am* in `"Hi, I am "`.

Is there a reason beneath this choice, or it's purely based on readability?

Comment: Probably when writing the tutorial he had a version of the code where he used some other expression (e.g. a variable) instead of the string literal `"Hi, I am"`. Then he decided to replace each instance with the literal by find&replace…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given the example, no difference.   Often it just develops out of habit

usually if you are using variables,   a + " " + b,  its a bad habit to put the spaces in the variables themselves because it limits how you can compose them together.

So,

```
"Hi, I am" + " " + name;
```

might become

```
greeting + " " + name
```

and its already in the correct format for whitespace

Answer (score 2):

Just to make the code clearer to read. the first syntax isn't usually used with static text, but with variable, so that you never miss the space.

```
var1 + " " + var2
```

This way you make sure you never miss the space in the end of var1 each time you give it a value

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing coding work to be internationalized, then the first form has an advantage.

Super-simple example...

```
var text = {en: {hello: "Hello"}, sp: {hello: "Hola"}};
var lang = "en";
var name = "John";

console.log(text[lang].hello + " " + name);
```

Using this style, the translator never has to worry about trailing spaces and you've made everything consistent.

Comment: tbh, if you want to internationalize, a better approach would be to use format strings. Some languages might start the sentence with the name instead of starting with the greeting.

Comment: Hence the 'super-simple' example, but yes, quite correct.  A vast majority of what I output seems to come down to `<keyword>`/`<value>` and we don't bother with format strings for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can write either way. No method you can say is the best. How you like to code is important.

Anyway I would also choose the first one. See below is an example:

```
var nameString = function (name) {
    var str = "Hi, I am"; // Often we don't have space after last of string
    return str + " " + name;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this one

```
var nameString = function (name) {
    return "Hi, I am " + name;
};

console.log(nameString("jim"));
```

over this one

```
var nameString = function (name) {
    return "Hi, I am" + " " + name;
};

console.log(nameString("jim"));
```

just because strings are immutable in Javascript, and it seems like a bad habit to have to concatenate three strings instead of two. It won't be a performance issue for such a small amount of text though.

So I would think people are just doing it for readability's sake since it is definitely not a performance plus.

[Here's](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Optimization#String_concatenation) some more info on the immutability of Javascript strings and concatenation: